# How to change currency on checkout with paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, currency

I am using AED as my base currency and PayPal is not Supporting AED. i want to convert it in to US Dolor while checkout with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial  [INR currency convert issue with paypal payment method in magento](http://chandreshrana.blogspot.com/2014/07/inr-currency-convert-issue-with-paypal.html)  or [Convert to USD payments made with PayPal for unaccepted currencies in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043933/convert-to-usd-payments-made-with-paypal-for-unaccepted-currencies-in-magento)

If you using multiple currency, you can try this tutorial : [Magento Multiple Currency Support For Paypal](http://www.magentostack.com/magento-multicurrency-support-for-paypal/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this module: https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

> This module is for Magento 1.7+ to Support Paypal payments for not
>   supported currencies by PayPal.

Answer provided here as well: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79666/1883

Comment: I tested and the module does not work for CE1.9

Comment: In Magento 1.9, the PayPal Standard Payment is replaced by PayPal Express Checkout. You may try enabling PayPal Standard Payment with the steps mentioned here: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-paypal-standard-payment-form-replaced-by-paypal-express-checkout-form-in-admin-payment-settings/ and then please check if the module works or not.

Comment: Hi @Mukesh, Thanks for reply, but does not work. 
The Paypal Website Payments Standard was already enabled.
I'm trying to find the problem with your module, but I can not.
It is the best solution that I have for this feature.