# INR not convert in to dollar in paypal in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

I am not able to convert INR To Dollar in magento 1.9.1, my base currency is INR.It's working on perfectly on ccavenue module but in the case of payPal it is not convert INR in to Dollar in PayPal. I have tried lot but not success. Below are links i.e. which are used by me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382883/magento-paypal-payment-showing-100-inr-as-100-usd

[How to change currency on checkout with paypal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70262/how-to-change-currency-on-checkout-with-paypal)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043933/convert-to-usd-payments-made-with-paypal-for-unaccepted-currencies-in-magento

Answer (score 3):

There's a Magento extension that supports PayPal for not supported currencies by PayPal: https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

Answered here as well: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79666/1883