# Cc-avenue Currency Conversion Issue with MCPG extension Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm Using Magento Extension For Cc-avenue by BlueZeal Which supports Multiple Currency 
By base Currency In INR  Store is **INR** with **Country = India** Supported
Base Currency In International Store : **Dollar** , **All Country Supported**

while Generating Bill The Currency Is Showing Proper Eg for 22$ its 1430 INR aprox.and vise versa showing correct but when its redirecting to CCAVENUE payment page it takes 22$ as 22 INR .

I have tried Solutions SImilar to this issue on SO but none of them worked!

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382883/magento-paypal-payment-showing-100-inr-as-100-usd
2. [How to change currency on checkout with paypal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70262/how-to-change-currency-on-checkout-with-paypal)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043933/convert-to-usd-payments-made-with-paypal-for-unaccepted-currencies-in-magento
4. [paypal express checkout for AED currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79071/paypal-express-checkout-for-aed-currency/79666#79666)
5. [INR not convert in to dollar in paypal in magento 1.9.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/inr-not-convert-in-to-dollar-in-paypal-in-magento-1-9-1)

Attached Is the Screenshot of The settings in admin panel

[image]

For the issue 
[image: Issue]

[image: Bill Generated]

Comment: Which is your store base currency ?

Comment: INR for india , for International Its Dollr

Comment: Did you changed any price related customization ?

Comment: no...only i have set up base currency and auto currency is on

Comment: @SHPatel can you tell me what exactly the issue is ? It only in the case when the data is sent to ccavnue page ,although the currency is working file

Answer (score 0):

Always keep currency on Website Level. This is what Magento allows by default. Even if you install an extn which allows you to set currency on Store level, it'll give you many problems. 
Make 2 websites in magento with one store and store view each. Change base currencies and then this extension will work well.

Thanks

Comment: for now i have made stores only

Answer (score 0):

change currency in ccavnue phtml file 
attached image take a look 
[image]